# Postgis know if point is part of linestring

Tags: postgis

I have a linestring and I want to know if a point is in it, I have tried ST_Intersects but it only works if the point is exactly as in the linestring.

I want to find points which are in the linestring but are not defined in it.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: so you want points NEAR the line?

Comment: I don't know if near is the right term but imagine a random point on the linestring, 
for instance if I got a-----b------c, I want to know if d is on that line, is it possible? or how to approach this problem? @nickves

Comment: `ST_Intersects` will find a point that lines along a line, regardless of whether it is also equal to one of the vertices of the line. If `ST_Intersects` has failed where you think it should not have failed, that will be because the point does not actually intersect the line, and you may instead want to find a point that is "near" the line—and you will have to define what is meant by "near".

Comment: A line does not have an area, so it cannot have geometries within. It's either part of the line or not.

Comment: That's what I meant, part of the line

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [ST_DWithin](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html)

Here's a nice example (is the line near the point to within 0.0001 units?) :

```
SELECT st_dwithin('LINESTRING ( 0 0, 0 2 )'::geometry, 'POINT(0.0001 0.0001)'::geometry, 0.0001);

st_dwithin
---------------
   t
```